# modal reactjs close time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I need my modal to close after a certain time, how can I do this?
this is what i have done so far

```
import React from 'react';
import IconcloseModal from './../../assets/icon/icon-cerrar-modal.png';
import './Modal.css'

const Modal = ({ typeModal, textModal, showModal, positionModal, closeModal }) => {
    let titleModal = '';
    if (typeModal === 'success')
        titleModal = '¡Bien hecho!';
    else if (typeModal === 'warning')
        titleModal = '¡Cuidado!';
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={(showModal) ? 'notify ' + positionModal + ' do-show' : 'notify ' + positionModal}
                data-notification-status={typeModal}>
                <div className="content-warning">
                    <h3>{titleModal}</h3>
                    <p> {textModal}</p>
                </div>
                <div onClick={closeModal} className="close-alert"><img src={IconcloseModal} alt="Logo cerrar modal" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the setTimout function for this.
Assuming that `closeModal` is a function you can implement it like this.
This will close the modal after 3 seconds.

```
function close() {
  setTimeout(() => closeModal(), 3000)
}
return(
...
<div onClick={close} className="close-alert"><img src={IconcloseModal} alt="Logo cerrar modal" /></div>
...
)
```